# Definition of Real Analytic function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm just starting to learn about real analytic functions, and ran into conflict with two definitions. In Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis", he says that $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is analytic if for each $x\in (a,b)$ there exists a $\delta>0$ and a power series $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_rh^r$ such that if |$h$|$<\delta$, then the series converges and $f(x+h)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}a_rh^r$, where $a_r=f^r(x)/r!$

This seems a little different from the most of the definitions I've seen: A function $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is analytic at $c\in (a,b)$ if there is some $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}f^r(c)/r!(x-c)^r$.

I'm having trouble seeing how these definitions are equivalent though, particularly the $f(x+h)$ vs $f(x)$. Is it because in Pugh's definition,if we let $y=x+h$, we get $f(y)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}f^r(x)/r!(y-x)^r$, so in Pugh's definition, $y$ plays the role of $x$ in the second definition, and Pugh's $x$ plays the role of $c$ in the second definition. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, you can make them consistent this way. But perhaps it would be less confusing if you exchange $x$ for $c$ in the first formula, so that then $x=c+h$ is the connection of both formulas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pugh - non-Pugh dictionary:

- $x$ (center of series) : $c$
- $h$ (displacement from the center) : $x-c$
- $x+h$ (argument of $f$): $x$

(The third line is the sum of the first two.)